# PKAddPassesViewController dismiss animation not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, passbook

I'm struggling with the PKAddPassesViewController.

If I don't implement the `addPassesViewControllerDidFinish:` delegate method, its dismissal is animated (looks like a cross dissolve). However as soon as I implement the method in my delegate, I can't get the controller to be dismissed with any animation. It just vanishes, no matter how I try to dismiss it from the delegate method: `dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES`, `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES`...

Any idea on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss controller in delegate method solved my problem.

```
-(void)addPassesViewControllerDidFinish:(PKAddPassesViewController *)controller {
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self updateData];
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below method:-

```
- (void)addPaymentPassViewController:(PKAddPaymentPassViewController *)controller
 generateRequestWithCertificateChain:(NSArray<NSData *> *)certificates
                               nonce:(NSData *)nonce
                      nonceSignature:(NSData *)nonceSignature
                   completionHandler:(void(^)(PKAddPaymentPassRequest *request))handler { }
```

I think some of the values in the PKAddPaymentPassRequest is nil, which will be passing to iOS using a handler.